# What is VIctim cache in intel machine? Can we disable it?

Tags: c, linux, caching, intel, cpu-cache

What is VIctim cache  in intel machine?

Can we disable it ? using gcc  or using bios or in linux  ?

Comment: Why would you want to disable something you don't know what it is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_cache#Victim_cache

Comment: @Eregrith, I had one doubt while discussion with my friend about eviction policy and while google it find from wiki, but had little doubt , so i posted it here for other description. thats it. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache):-

> A victim cache is a cache used to hold blocks evicted from a CPU cache
>   upon replacement. The victim cache lies between the main cache and its
>   refill path, and only holds blocks that were evicted from the main
>   cache. The victim cache is usually fully associative, and is intended
>   to reduce the number of conflict misses. Many commonly used programs
>   do not require an associative mapping for all the accesses. In fact,
>   only a small fraction of the memory accesses of the program require
>   high associativity. The victim cache exploits this property by
>   providing high associativity to only these accesses. It was introduced
>   by Norman Jouppi from DEC in 1990.[15] Intel's Crystal Well[16]
>   variant of its Haswell processors, equipped with Intel's Iris Pro GT3e
>   embedded graphics and 128 MB of eDRAM, introduced an on-package Level
>   4 cache which serves as a victim cache to the processors's Level 3
>   cache

Comment: Being just a copy - paste from Wikipedia, I would probably mark this as community wiki.

Comment: @MatteoItalia:- Yes thats correct. Made it the same! Thanks :)

Comment: @bholanath:- Yes L1 is the main cache. :)

Comment: As per the definition, so data evicted either from L1 stored temporarily in victim cache, and if there exist then also evicted data from L3 to victim cache as in  Intel's Iris Pro GT3e embedded graphics. So no victim cache benefits for evicted data from L2 cache ?

Comment: @bholanath: The eDRAM L4 on Broadwell caches evictions from L3 only.  But L3 is inclusive of the small per-core L2 and L1 caches.  L1 and L2 don't have victim caches.  They just evict into the next higher level.  (And L2 might not even need to write back to L3, since L3 is inclusive.  If it was cached in L2, it was already cached in L3 unless the copy in L2 is dirty.)